# How to awk with delimited file then pass the values to parameters as is?

Tags: printing, awk, do-while

how can I pass the values from a delimited text file to parameters (VW, MSG, DIV) as is?

```
BB|832|ONSA
AL||ONSL
|850|PCMS
```

Here's my code -

```
cat VPconfig.txt | sed 's/ //g' | awk -F"|" '{print $1, $2, $3}' | while read VW MSG DIV
```

Output:

```
BB 832 ONSA
AL ONSA
850 PCMS
```

I'm getting incorrect values of VW, MSG, and DIV. Values should be null (for MSG second loop) and (for VW third loop).

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. Could you indicate what is the desired output?

Comment: Hi @fedorqui, I want to get the correct vaues (accepts null and space) of $VW,$MSG and $DIV once echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but one of these should help...

**Option 1**

Use this one if you don't really need or want to use `awk` but have something else in mind that you plan to do in `bash`:

```
while IFS=\| read VW MSG DIV; do 
   echo $VW,$MSG,$DIV; 
done < VPconfig.txt
```

**Output**:

```
BB,832,ONSA
AL,,ONSL
,850,PCMS
```

**Option 2**

Use this one if you do want to use `awk` and want the simplest invocation:

```
awk -F\| '{print $1,$2,$3}' VPconfig.txt
BB 832 ONSA
AL  ONSL
 850 PCMS
```

Or, if you want the output fields separated by commas, use this variation:

```
awk -F\| '{print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=, VPconfig.txt
BB,832,ONSA
AL,,ONSL
,850,PCMS
```

**Option 3**

Use this variation of the previous option if you want a simple invocation of `awk` and to use friendly variable names within `awk`:

```
awk -F\| '{VW=$1;MSG=$2;DIV=$3; print VW,MSG,DIV}' VPconfig.txt
```

**Option 4**

Use this one if you want to do something else with the variables in `bash` and also pass them into `awk` with nice, user-friendly names:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=\| read VW MSG DIV; do 
   awk -v VW="$VW" -v MSG="$MSG" -v DIV="$DIV" 'BEGIN{print VW,MSG,DIV}'
done < VPconfig.txt
```

Comment: awk could just be `awk -F\| '{$1=$1}1' file`